# How should I send an ArrayList of Bitmaps from one activity to another ? I

Tags: android, arraylist, android-intent, bitmap, parcelable

Code in the sending activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("bitmaps",  bitmapArrayList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Code in the receiving activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    bitmapArrayList =  intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bitmaps");
```

The app crashes as soon as go to the receiving activity. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You should not send that kind of data from Activity A to B. Use some kind of medium-class between them where you can set this data and then retrieve, like repository. Bundles and Intents are not designed for large data. Also consider keeping Ids or URI-s and access them from another activity, rather than sending plain bitmap directly

documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions are of moderate size.

Comment: Okay, I''ll look into it.

Comment: Can you provide me with some links where I can to learn to do this through URI-s?

Comment: I guess there is no specific link/tutorial to learn how to do this through URI. URI will be an address to your files if you are creating bitmaps from them. And what I meant in the answer is that keep a reference only and do not send raw bitmap in intents, pass the id or URI of the file and in another activity retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap extends Parcelable, which means that you can provide a list like this:

```
 ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
// Poupulate list here

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", bitmapList);
```

Then you can convert this to a Bitmap[] in your receiving activity:

```
Bitmap[] bitmapArray = bitmapList.toArray(new Bitmap[bitmapList.size()]);
```

But keep in mind that it's generally bad practice to put too much stuff in your intent. It's preferable to have your data stored (DB, filesystem, singleton,...) and pass URIs or IDs.

Comment: The app still crashes even after storing it in a Bitmap Array.

Comment: No, but the app crashed.